# Drupal Paging module doesn't show the number of pages

Tags: php, drupal, pagination

I am finishing some edits on a drupal project that was done by another programmer (I have no contact with him). I'm a newbie and trying to find out how the Paging module works. There are no numbers of pages showing. I suppose the programmer added some custom module or something.

I found a file named "pager.php" in the project's own theme folder with this function, that is probably doing the pagination:

```
function _my_pager_link($page, $text, $class, $title) {
$query = array();
$query[] = drupal_query_string_encode(array(
    'page' => implode(',', $page)), array());
$querystring = pager_get_querystring();
if ($querystring != '') {
    $query[] = $querystring;
}
$attributes['title'] = $title;
$attributes['class'] = $class;
return l("<span>$text</span>", $_GET['q'], array('html' => TRUE,
    'attributes' => $attributes,
    'query' => count($query) ? implode('&', $query) : NULL));
}

function my_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 5) {
global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

$curr = $pager_page_array[$element];
$total = $pager_total[$element];
$output = '';
if ($total > 1) {
    $output .= '<div class="pager">';
    if ($curr > 0) {
        $page_new = pager_load_array($curr - 1, $element, $pager_page_array);
        $output .= _my_pager_link($page_new, t('‹ previous'), 'pager-prev', t('Go to previous page'));
    }
    if ($curr < $total - 1) {
        $page_new = pager_load_array($curr + 1, $element, $pager_page_array);
        $output .= _my_pager_link($page_new, t('next ›'), 'pager-next', t('Go to next page'));
    }
    $output .= '<div class="cleaner"></div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    }
return $output;
}
```

Now there is just 'previous page' and 'next page' on the web. I would like it to be like this
'previous page '... 2 3 4 ... 'next page'

How can I add the list of pages there?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_pager/6

Add salt and voila!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the global values like so:

```
global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;
$pager_page_array[0] = $your_page_count_goes_here;
$pager_total[0] = $your_page_total_goes_here;
```

And then you can call `theme('pager', ...)` or any custom paging theme function that you may have.